# ASP.NET webform Access-control allow orgin not working?

Tags: asp.net, forms, web

I have an ASP.NET WebForms project. In a button click event I call a JavaScript method to perfom an XMLHttpRequest to get all country names in JSON-format. I got an access control allow origin error. How do I fix it?

```js
var url = "http://country.io/names.json";
function meth1() {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();           
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.status == 200 && xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
        console.log("ready " + this.readyState + "   status  " + this.status);
        console.log(this.response);
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("get", url, true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
      <h4>Test xmlhttprequest on cors</h4>
      <input type="button" value="Get ajax cors" onclick="meth1()" />
  </div>
</form>
```

This is the code I have set on the server side:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var context = HttpContext.Current;                   
    context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:53410/");
    context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
    context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header twice, could you tell us which value is actually send back by the server to the client?

Comment: it return json data

Comment: {"BD": "Bangladesh", "BE": "Belgium", "BF": "Burkina Faso", "BG": "Bulgaria", "BA": "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "BB": "Barbados", "WF": "Wallis and Futuna", "SM": "San Marino", "SL": "Sierra Leone", "SC": "Seychelles", "KZ": "Angola", "AQ": "Antarctica", "AS": "American Samoa", "AR": "Argentina", "AU": , "QA": "Qatar", "MZ": "Mozambique"}

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a request to a website which does not set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header (http://country.io/names.json). If you do an `OPTIONS` request to this URL, you'll get the following result:

```
<h1>403 Forbidden</h1>
<ul>
    <li>Code: AccessForbidden</li>
    <li>Message: CORSResponse: CORS is not enabled for this bucket.</li>
    <li>Method: GET</li>
    <li>ResourceType: BUCKET</li>
</ul>
```

This means that if you do an `XMLHttpRequest` to this website, your browser will automatically block the response.

You could download and save the JSON file and store it on your local server so you can access it via an `XMLHttpRequest`.

**For example:**

```
var url = "http://localhost:<portnumber>/names.json";

function meth1() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();           
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200 && xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
            console.log("ready " + this.readyState + "   status  " + this.status);
            console.log(this.response);
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("get", url, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: hello Baksteen, thank you very much, now I understand , please give me the code how to execute with OPTIONS request to this URL part, so any open/free url , I will check and then I use it for example this url does it set Access-control-allow origin. https://api.postalpincode.in/pincode/606001, please help me

Comment: can you give me a sample url needs to set Access-control-allow orign and then consume the data, so I can learn better, please kindly help me.

Comment: There are many programs where you can do requests with. Personally I'd recommend [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/). You can easily set headers and do an `OPTIONS` request with it.

Comment: Hello sir, thank you for your response, I can get result in postman the followin api,  http://api.worldbank.org/countries/all
https://api.postalpincode.in/pincode/606001, but I could not run in visual studio webform and get result.

Comment: hello sir, can you help how do I consume this API with xmlhttprequest . https://api.postalpincode.in/pincode/606001, Please help me.

Comment: when I consume by xmlhttprequest, the below error I see on the console. Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.postalpincode.in/pincode/606001' from origin 'http://localhost:53410' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: You cannot do it with XMLHttpRequest in the browser because the postalpincode.in api doesn't send an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header

Comment: Hello Baksteen, Thanks your continues teaching,  can you give one example code in jquery, angular how to consume a service by setting Access-Control-Allow-origin header in Visual studio environment.. Please kindlay help me.